# Is there a println type function that works with filesystem in F#?

Tags: f#

I am looking for the most natural way to save data to a text file. Could someone provide a simple example? Is there a function from the println family that does the job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fprintf` (and `fprintfn`) function works like `printf` and `sprintf` but takes a `TextWriter` to write to. You can found out more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370327.aspx).

Note the whole [Core.Printf module is interesting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560).

A very simple example:

```
using (new StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt")) (fun file ->
    fprintfn file "test %i" 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

fprintf and the like may not be the right way to go, depending how you are generating the data.  Sometimes it can be as easy as this:

```
let SaveMe() =
    let data =  [0..1000]
                |> List.map (fun i -> sprintf "string number %i" i)
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\myfile.txt", data)
```